# How to retrieve Chat history with android smack client

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I'm developing a chatting application where we have deployed the eJabberd on server and using smack library client for android.
Now the problem is i was not able to get the previous chat history to show. Please help me out in getting the chat history.

Comment: What did you try ? What is the result ?

Comment: Giving more details is important because there is several things that could be called "history" in XMPP.

Comment: Actually i dint get any API for getting chat history using Smack Library.

Comment: I had given detailed answer on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574395/6771052[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574395/6771052)

Answer (score 1):

Chat history (latest x messages) are retrieved as defined in [XEP-0045 Multi-User Chat](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-history). Message Archive are retrieved as defined in [XEP-0313 Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html). Use one of those specifications.

Comment: @MathaN Are you getting chat history using smack?

Comment: It means we do not get the history from the Xmpp smack.As i notice in IOS , they are easily getting the one to one chatting history. If there any way to get the XMPP chatting history.Please let me know.. Thanks

Comment: So we can't get chat history between two users ?

Comment: @shuvro Yes you can get message history between two users. As I explained: Query the Message Archive.