# How to get the chat history from the XMPP smack:- Android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I want to get the chat history from the *XMPP SMACK library* but not able to achieve it.Currently i am able to communicate between the two end users but not getting the chat history.
I have used the `Sqlite` to store the user chat conversation to achieve it but the **problem** is that it become the device dependent.Means when the user login with the different device than he is not able to get their history (Chat conversation)

As i came to know that in the **IOS** their is the library who store the chat history of the user, library link:- [Click here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)

I have searched for it on the `StackOverFlow`but did not get the proper solution for it, My searched link are as follow:-
1.[First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961720/how-retrieve-chat-history-using-java-smack-library-from-openfire-server)
2.[Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545057/how-to-get-openfire-chat-history-on-android-device-with-asmack)
3.[Third link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130504/how-to-retrieve-chat-history-with-android-smack-client)
4.[Forth link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635034/smack-api-read-chat-history-from-openfire-server)

***Is there any library available to get the XMPP chat history***, Please let me know Thanks :)

Comment: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html

Comment: Hope this is helpfull.. if not let me know, we can discuss more

Comment: @ArfanMirza Thanks for your comment..Did u achieve it by above link..I am not getting what to do with it ..Please let me know

Comment: Did you installed that module??

Comment: Which module i have to install bro...??Please help

Comment: Are you working on xmpp server side too? or only Mobile app developer?

Comment: Bro i am only the mobile app developer..

Comment: then ask your xmpp developer to give you chat history!

Comment: @ArfanMirza Means there is not coding from my end??
Server need the lines of codes to provide the chat history to the mobile user???

Comment: Yes.. if there is xmpp server exists..:) if you are doing locally then let me know

Comment: Actually we are using our own server to perform XMPP chatting..Means i have to say to my server team that they should provide me the chat history between any two user..... Am i right?? @ArfanMirza

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Thanks @ArfanMirza bhai :)....    But as i see in the IOS , they are using the some library to achieve it..In IOS and android both are using the same server...In android there is not possible to achieve it?

Comment: What us name of library ?? Which used in IOS

Comment: Bro these is the link for the library please check it once :- 
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: that library is viewController, means it show only messages in nice/attractive format/UI ..

Comment: Yes bro... Can we get such type of libraryt in andriod also

Comment: k dost @ArfanMirza

Comment: @ArfanMirza, i have verified with my server team that they have already enabled archiving of messages and thats why ios client app is getting chat history, So what i am looking for is a Java wrapper(or code) to request my xmpp server to get chat history. Can you please help me with this!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have ios code??

Comment: @ArfanMirza ...My IOS team have used these link to get the chat history..First link :- https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios    And second one is these :- github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController    ...As they said to me that in these above IOS library there is WRAPPER implemented already to get the chat history.....So i am also searching for the such wrapper code for the ANDROID ..If you have any idea about it than please help !!!!!!!Thanks

Comment: thanks for asking again... i develop an app few months ago, i use the xmpp service to get history of chat between two users.. you have to dig into ios code, and check how that is working..

Comment: Does your problem fixed?

Comment: @ArfanMirza ... Not brother :( ...Not fixed yet

Comment: find email in profile, and ping me, i will detail discuss with you!

Comment: @shuvro ...Not yet bro.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125713/how-to-retrieve-one-to-one-chat-history-from-openfire-using-asmack-android/60167916#60167916