# one to one chat history with open fire and smack

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

I have installed open fire in my system and by using postman tool i am able to create the user and by using smack  i can able to send the message to other user also.. but the problem is that i dont know that how to fetch the chat history between two users..it means if i sent the from and to user names i need to fetch the previous chat history.
I am able to see the chat history in the open fire servers--> archieving folder..
But i am not getting that how to fetch the chat history.
Is there any **Rest API's are available to fetch the chat history** between two users..

Please provide any possible solution

Thank You

This is the chat history that I can see

[image]

Comment: If you are using `MAM` then you can get the history from `MamManager`.See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961720/how-retrieve-chat-history-using-java-smack-library-from-openfire-server) and similar questions .

Comment: Thanks for your response .but i am not using mammanager in my implementation class

Comment: `mammanager` is Part of Smack 4.2 i guess . And `MAM` plugin is available for openfire . If you go to plugin in Open Fire console you will see it as Message Archive . Read https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use get chat history from Openfire with smack:

1. As you have already done, enable MAM (XEP-0313) by installing the [MonitoringService](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html) plugin in Openfire.
2. Now from the Openfire server go to: Server>Archiving>Archiving Settings and check "Archive one-to-one chats" and "Archive group chats" and save click "update setting".
3. From now on any chats will be saved on Openfire. Start a new chat with someone and reinstall your android app.
4. MAM is a part of "[smack-experimental](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html)". So you must add this line to your Gradle:

   ```
   implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.2'
   ```
5. After a successful connection and authorization for one of them, you can get chat history page by page or as you need with this code:

   ```
   MamManager manager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
   MamManager.MamQueryResult r = manager.mostRecentPage([userBareJID], [numberOfMessages]);
   if (r.forwardedMessages.size() >= 1) //printing first of them
   {
       Message message = (Message) r.forwardedMessages.get(0).getForwardedStanza();
       Log.i("mam", "message received" + message.getBody());
   }
   ```

Comment: Will you please give me some suggestions for this issue also::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682932/cant-able-to-upload-file-through-spark2-7-7-client-to-open-fire?noredirect=1#comment90328695_51682932

Comment: i have already voted for your valuable response but due to less reputations i earned it is not considering my vote

Comment: You need to add below gradle dependency for using MamManager class


"implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.2.2"