# Cant able to upload file through spark(2.7.7) client to open fire

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

We are trying to build a chat application between two users. So, we prefer to use openfire . I have installed **openfire(4.2.3)** in **Ubuntu** server and created 
two test users through admin panel.I can able to chat between two users using 
**spark client(2.7.7)or (2.8.3)**  but the problem is that i cant able to send a file to the another user using spark client and also even we tried to share through android code also .It is not working .

I can able to browse the file using the spark client but it is not sending to the other user . even if he is in online also not able to send

In open fire system also i have enabled the **file transfer settings**

[When the user is in offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTZHX.png)
Thanks in advance

**Any one can please help me with this issue** .

Comment: Is there any error or something else ?

Comment: Thanks for your response . Here while uploading the file through spark client it is not even getting any error also .It will just browse but not able to send the other user